# Spinner, add up/down arrow button listener

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

is it possible to add click listener for Spinner up/down buttons?
I need this behavior, because when I add Modify or Selection listeners, all changes that I enter manually to the Spinner field are also commited, which is not acceptable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to `SWT.Verify` and check the `keyCode` of the `Event`.

This value will be `0` for the button presses. Thus, you can tell the `Spinner` to ignore events when the `keyCode` is not equal to `0`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(shell, SWT.NONE);
    spinner.setMaximum(100);
    spinner.setMinimum(0);
    spinner.setIncrement(10);

    spinner.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if(arg0.keyCode != 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Value edited");
                arg0.doit = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Button pressed");
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to share event data between VerifyListener and ModifyListener?

Comment: I mean this: possibility to change value by up/down spinner buttons and also ability to change value manually in text field by pressing enter or focus lost.

Comment: @Steve You will have to be more specific. My current answer disables editing of the "text/value", because this is what you were asking for. If you want to enable both ways of editing, but still be able to distinguish between them in the `Listener`, just remove the `arg0.doit = false`.

Comment: yes, you are right. I had to be more specific at the first place. Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful!